# form is NOT submitted to store function Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, request, store

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxbzp.png)thanks for helping  me
Iam new in Laravel
Trying to submit form into store method :
I made the following validation Request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'photo' =>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif',
        'category' =>'required|array|min:1',
        'category.*.name' =>'required',
        'category.*.abbr' =>'required',
        'category.*.active' =>'required'

   ];
}
```

}

And This is my form route part goes to store method here:

```
<form class="form" action="{{route('admin.mainCategories.store')}}" method="POST"
                                          enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        @csrf
```

Comment: please add more specific problem you got, like what is "NOT submitted to store" your insert function or any error you got

Comment: Thanks Kelvin for reply, I mean when press submit form-> I get back to url of http://localhost:81/ecommerce/admin/mainCategories/create  NOThttp://localhost:81/ecommerce/admin/mainCategories/store   => so when I try to return request in store function :I just have a plain form again, hope it is clear.

Comment: My store method in controller:      public function store(MainCategoryRequest $request){

        $main_category = collect($request->category);
        $filter = $main_category->filter(function($key , $value){
            return $value['abbr'] == get_default_function();

        });

        $default_category =  array_values($filter->all());

    }

Comment: if you press submit then get back to url, its mean your validation is failed

Comment: Nice tip,I reviewd it , can Not get why it is failing, do not know what Iam missing

Comment: @Shaza well why don't you look at the validation errors. There are countless examples of how to print out the errors.